# Tikz: connect two nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-arrows

I have many nodes and want to connect two of them, but in such way that the path is not scratch off nodes, which are between these two like in the [image] example below (I want to connect `L_0` and `R_0`):

To create this path I used following command:

```
\path [line,dashed] (l0) edge [] node {} (r0);
```

Comment: You want to bend the line so that it won't touch other nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) {a};
    \node[right=1cm of a] (b) {B};
    \node[right=1cm of b] (c) {C};
    \node[right=1cm of c] (d) {D};
    \node[right=1cm of d] (e) {E};
    \node[right=1cm of e] (f) {F};
    \draw [dashed] (a) to[bend left] node {} (f);
    \draw [red,dashed] (a) -- ++(0,5mm) -| node {} (f);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking exactly about something like the red dashed line! :)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you use the `to` syntax and specify the `out` and `in` angles. Here are a few examples and perhaps adjust the `distance`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[thick, dashed]
  \foreach [count=\i] \x in {$L_0$, $R_3$, $R_1$, $L_2$, $R_0$} {
      \node (\i) at (\i,0) {\x};
  }
  \draw [olive  ] (1.north) to[out=50, in=100] (5.north);
  \draw [red    ] (1.north) to[out=30, in=150] (5.north);
  \draw [blue   ] (1.south) to[out=-30, in=-150] (5.south);
  \draw [magenta] (1.south) to[out=-30, in=-150, distance=2.5cm] (5.south);
  \draw [orange ] (1.south) to[out=-70, in=-110] (5.south);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and examples, which are very helpful!